# Write this Scala Matrix multiplication in Haskell

Tags: scala, haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you overload + in haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308015/can-you-overload-in-haskell)

Can you implement a Matrix class and an * operator that will work on two matrices?:

```
scala> val x = Matrix(3, 1,2,3,4,5,6)  
x: Matrix =   
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]  
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]  

scala> x*x.transpose  
res0: Matrix =   
[14.0, 32.0]  
[32.0, 77.0]
```

and just so people don't say that it's hard, here is the Scala implementation (courtesy of [Jonathan Merritt](http://jsmerritt.blogspot.com/2008/07/matrix-multiplication-in-scala.html)):

```
class Matrix(els: List[List[Double]]) {  

    /** elements of the matrix, stored as a list of  
      its rows */  
    val elements: List[List[Double]] = els  
    def nRows: Int = elements.length  
    def nCols: Int = if (elements.isEmpty) 0   
                     else elements.head.length  

    /** all rows of the matrix must have the same  
        number of columns */  
    require(elements.forall(_.length == nCols))  

    /* Add to each elem of matrix */
    private def addRows(a: List[Double],   
                        b: List[Double]):   
      List[Double] =   
        List.map2(a,b)(_+_)  

    private def subRows(a: List[Double],   
                        b: List[Double]):List[Double] =  
        List.map2(a,b)(_-_)  

    def +(other: Matrix): Matrix = {  
      require((other.nRows == nRows) &&   
              (other.nCols == nCols))  
      new Matrix(  
        List.map2(elements, other.elements)  
          (addRows(_,_))
      )  
    }  

    def -(other: Matrix): Matrix = {  
      require((other.nRows == nRows) &&   
              (other.nCols == nCols))  
      new Matrix(  
        List.map2(elements, other.elements)  
          (subRows(_,_))  
      )  
    }  

    def transpose(): Matrix = new Matrix(List.transpose(elements))    

    private def dotVectors(a: List[Double],   
                       b: List[Double]): Double = {  
      val multipliedElements =   
        List.map2(a,b)(_*_)  
      (0.0 /: multipliedElements)(_+_)  
    }  

    def *(other: Matrix): Matrix = {  
      require(nCols == other.nRows)  
      val t = other.transpose()  
      new Matrix(  
        for (row <- elements) yield {  
          for (otherCol <- t.elements)  
            yield dotVectors(row, otherCol)  
        }  
      )  

    override def toString(): String = {  
        val rowStrings =   
        for (row <- elements)   
          yield row.mkString("[", ", ", "]")  
        rowStrings.mkString("", "\n", "\n")  
    }  
}  

/* Matrix constructor from a bunch of numbers */
object Matrix {  
  def apply(nCols: Int, els: Double*):Matrix = {  
    def splitRowsWorker(  
      inList: List[Double],   
      working: List[List[Double]]):  
    List[List[Double]] =  
      if (inList.isEmpty)  
        working  
      else {  
        val (a, b) = inList.splitAt(nCols)  
        splitRowsWorker(b, working + a)  
      }  
    def splitRows(inList: List[Double]) =  
      splitRowsWorker(inList, List[List[Double]]())  
    val rows: List[List[Double]] =   
      splitRows(els.toList)  
    new Matrix(rows)  
  }  
}
```

**EDIT** I understood that strictly speaking the answer is No: overloading * is not possible without side-effects of defining also a + and others or special tricks. The [numeric-prelude package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude) describes it best:

> In some cases, the hierarchy is not finely-grained enough: Operations
>   that are often defined independently are lumped together. For
>   instance, in a financial application one might want a type "Dollar",
>   or in a graphics application one might want a type "Vector". It is
>   reasonable to add two Vectors or Dollars, but not, in general,
>   reasonable to multiply them. But the programmer is currently forced to
>   define a method for '(*)' when she defines a method for '(+)'.

Comment: The answers to your previous question showed it exactly. I don't see how they are wishy-washy.

Comment: Not really. It left out implementation of a lot of other Num operations undefined or something like that. I want to know if there is  "correct" way of doing this, or if it's IMPOSSIBLE in haskell (maybe people don't want to admit it?). In Scala - there is no question that this is OK! In any case - one way to settle this for sure is to implement the example above in Haskell.

Comment: There are 7 `Num` operations: `(+)`, `(*)`, `(-)`, `negate`, `signum`, `abs`, `fromInteger`. The first four, no problem; `signum` I suppose should return a unit matrix that is a scalar multiple of the input, `abs` should return a scalar (and it can't, because the typeclass insists it must return another matrix), and `fromInteger` doesn't make sense. OK, fine, make `abs` and `fromInteger` return errors. That's not perfect but it'll do --- you're already resigned to getting runtime errors when you add two matrices of different sizes. Could someone else expand on the Numeric Prelude, please?

Comment: So Haskell has the operations like + and * reserved (according to you and the answer by opqdonut). That is why I like Scala - it seems elegant in it's design and shows forethought.

Comment: No, the `+` and `*` are not "reserved". They are just functions that happen to be part of the same type class (which is very much like an interface in Java). This type class is in the prelude which means it is imported by default. To implement this "interface", you should implement *all* of its functions, which are the ones mentioned by @dave4420.

Comment: Ok... so they can be overridden? Sorry I feel like I'm going in cricles...

Comment: For square matrices it's natural for fromInteger to return a diagonal matrix.  And you can use the determinant as the absolute value.

Comment: Voted to close.  Drozzy does not appear to be interested in useful answers or solving a real problem, only in arguing that Haskell is worse than Python because it is not the same as Python.

Comment: @drozzy - It's being downvoted because people don't believe you're asking in good faith.  The answer is unequivocally yes.  You can either make a new `Num` instance or use the standard Prelude's `(*)` qualified.  Yet you persist in arguing that the answer is "No", because neither option behaves exactly as you want.  This gives the impression that you neither understand Haskell's semantics nor are willing to put forth an effort to learn.  This leaves responders wondering why you're asking at all, and the conclusions jumped to will not be good.

Comment: See the accepted answer to my other question of how it was answered to my satisfcation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308015/can-you-overload-in-haskell/8331010#8331010 
I am sorry if I don't accept answers that don't answer my question, but that is just me :-)

Comment: @JohnL But I don't know Haskell! This is the only reason I am asking. I want to know if it can do it prior to me starting to learn it. Why can't I ask questions about something I don't know?

Comment: @MikeHartl I've removed that statement, and the accepted answer to my other question, is indeed, exact.

Comment: @drozzy - Of course there's nothing wrong with asking questions (SO would be in a pickle otherwise!). Seems like you were just a bit confused (and I would argue that certain ...imprecise... answers/comments were misleading), and I think some of your comments were mistaken as non-constructive.  But please don't give up on the language (or community) just yet; Haskell can certainly be difficult to learn but it's extremely rewarding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It'll be perfectly safe with a smart constructor and stored dimensions. Of course there are no natural implementations for the operations `signum` and `fromIntegral` (or maybe a diagonal matrix would be fine for the latter).

```hs
module Matrix (Matrix(),matrix,matrixTranspose) where

import Data.List (transpose)

data Matrix a = Matrix {matrixN :: Int, 
                        matrixM :: Int,
                        matrixElems :: [[a]]}
                deriving (Show, Eq)

matrix :: Int -> Int -> [[a]] -> Matrix a
matrix n m vals
  | length vals /= m            = error "Wrong number of rows"
  | any (/=n) $ map length vals = error "Column length mismatch"
  | otherwise = Matrix n m vals

matrixTranspose (Matrix m n vals) = matrix n m (transpose vals)

instance Num a => Num (Matrix a) where

  (+) (Matrix m n vals) (Matrix m' n' vals')
    | m/=m' = error "Row number mismatch"
    | n/=n' = error "Column number mismatch"
    | otherwise = Matrix m n (zipWith (zipWith (+)) vals vals')

  abs (Matrix m n vals) = Matrix m n (map (map abs) vals)

  negate (Matrix m n vals) = Matrix m n (map (map negate) vals)

  (*) (Matrix m n vals) (Matrix n' p vals')
    | n/=n' = error "Matrix dimension mismatch in multiplication"
    | otherwise = let tvals' = transpose vals'
                      dot x y = sum $ zipWith (*) x y
                      result = map (\col -> map (dot col) tvals') vals
                  in Matrix m p result
```

Test it in ghci:

```hs
*Matrix> let a = matrix 3 2 [[1,0,2],[-1,3,1]]
*Matrix> let b = matrix 2 3 [[3,1],[2,1],[1,0]]
*Matrix> a*b
Matrix {matrixN = 3, matrixM = 3, matrixElems = [[5,1],[4,2]]}
```

Since my `Num` instance is generic, it even works for complex matrices out of the box:

```hs
Prelude Data.Complex Matrix> let c = matrix 2 2 [[0:+1,1:+0],[5:+2,4:+3]]
Prelude Data.Complex Matrix> let a = matrix 2 2 [[0:+1,1:+0],[5:+2,4:+3]]
Prelude Data.Complex Matrix> let b = matrix 2 3 [[3:+0,1],[2,1],[1,0]]
Prelude Data.Complex Matrix> a
Matrix {matrixN = 2, matrixM = 2, matrixElems = [[0.0 :+ 1.0,1.0 :+ 0.0],[5.0 :+ 2.0,4.0 :+ 3.0]]}
Prelude Data.Complex Matrix> b
Matrix {matrixN = 2, matrixM = 3, matrixElems = [[3.0 :+ 0.0,1.0 :+ 0.0],[2.0 :+ 0.0,1.0 :+ 0.0],[1.0 :+ 0.0,0.0 :+ 0.0]]}
Prelude Data.Complex Matrix> a*b
Matrix {matrixN = 2, matrixM = 3, matrixElems = [[2.0 :+ 3.0,1.0 :+ 1.0],[23.0 :+ 12.0,9.0 :+ 5.0]]}
```

---

**EDIT: new material**

Oh, you want to just override the `(*)` function without any `Num` stuff. That's possible to o but you'll have to remember that the Haskell standard library has reserved `(*)` for use in the `Num` class.

```hs
module Matrix where

import qualified Prelude as P
import Prelude hiding ((*))
import Data.List (transpose)

class Multiply a where
  (*) :: a -> a -> a

data Matrix a = Matrix {matrixN :: Int, 
                        matrixM :: Int,
                        matrixElems :: [[a]]}
                deriving (Show, Eq)

matrix :: Int -> Int -> [[a]] -> Matrix a
matrix n m vals
  | length vals /= m            = error "Wrong number of rows"
  | any (/=n) $ map length vals = error "Column length mismatch"
  | otherwise = Matrix n m vals

matrixTranspose (Matrix m n vals) = matrix n m (transpose vals)

instance P.Num a => Multiply (Matrix a) where
  (*) (Matrix m n vals) (Matrix n' p vals')
    | n/=n' = error "Matrix dimension mismatch in multiplication"
    | otherwise = let tvals' = transpose vals'
                      dot x y = sum $ zipWith (P.*) x y
                      result = map (\col -> map (dot col) tvals') vals
                  in Matrix m p result


a = matrix 3 2 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b = a * matrixTranspose
```

Testing in ghci:

```hs
*Matrix> b
Matrix {matrixN = 3, matrixM = 3, matrixElems = [[14,32],[32,77]]}
```

There. Now if a third module wants to use both the `Matrix` version of `(*)` and the `Prelude` version of `(*)` it'll have to of course import one or the other qualified. But that's just business as usual.

I could've done all of this without the `Multiply` type class but this implementation leaves our new shiny `(*)` open for extension in other modules.

Comment: __"Haskell standard library has reserved (*) for use in the Num class"__ That is EXACTLY what I wanted to know. I wanted to know how "flexible" Haskell was before I started learning it. Thank you. Wow, this took really long time to figure out.

Comment: @drozzy: also, I'll add that Haskellers tend to use new operators (like the `|+|` from your previous question) instead of overloading when overloading isn't exactly the right thing. This is a big contrast to languages like C++ or Python where the set of operators is limited so people have to keep reusing (or actually misusing) them.

Comment: I think Haskellers use new operators way too often. But besides that it seems to me that they "defend" their use of new operators as being right - when the fact is they have no choice. So they answer to my question (this and previous) should have been: NO, you cannot override + (or *). Period.

Comment: As has already been shown, you can override + and * just fine.  You just have to make explicit that you do so.

Comment: Thanks opqdonut! I think I understand now. If you do define a custom type with a * operator, it will overshadow the standard *. So if I wanted to do 2*2 I'd have to do something like `2 Prelude.* 2`

Comment: "That is EXACTLY what I wanted to know. I wanted to know how "flexible" Haskell was before I started learning it." - then you should have said EXACTLY that in your question. I'm sorry that it took too long to figure out.

Comment: Well, I wanted to know that haskell library has * reserved for Num class. I mean I couldn't have asked that if I didn't know about it - could I?

Comment: Just to make this explicit: the "reserved" here is not at all the same as the "reserved" in "`case`, `let`, and `where` are reserved words".  You can happily define a `(*)` function in your new Haskell module, but it's like defining a new type in Scala called `Seq`.  You *can*, but there's already a default.  The difference is that in Haskell, functions live in global scope, whereas in Scala, they live in types/classes/modules do.

Comment: I just want to comment that there would be a fairly natural way to apply `signum` at least to square matrices: just apply it to every eigenvalue (with some extra care in the case of a rank deficient matrix).

Answer (score 8):

Alright, there's a lot of confusion about what's happening here floating around, and it's not being helped by the fact that the Haskell term "class" does *not* line up with the OO term "class" in any meaningful way. So let's try to make a careful answer. This answer starts with Haskell's module system.

In Haskell, when you import a module `Foo.Bar`, it creates a new set of bindings. For each variable `x` exported by the module `Foo.Bar`, you get a new name `Foo.Bar.x`. In addition, you may:

- import qualified or not. If you import qualified, nothing more happens. If you do not, an additional name without the module prefix is defined; in this case, just plain old `x` is defined.
- change the qualification prefix or not. If you import `as Alias`, then the name `Foo.Bar.x` is not defined, but the name `Alias.x` is.
- hide certain names. If you hide name `foo`, then neither the plain name `foo` nor any qualified name (like `Foo.Bar.foo` or `Alias.foo`) is defined.

Furthermore, names may be *multiply defined*. For example, if `Foo.Bar` and `Baz.Quux` both export the variable `x`, and I import both modules without qualification, then the name `x` refers to *both* `Foo.Bar.x` and `Baz.Quux.x`. If the name `x` is never used in the resulting module, this clash is ignored; otherwise, a compiler error asks you to provide more qualification.

Finally, if none of your imports mention the module `Prelude`, the following implicit import is added:

```
import Prelude
```

This imports the `Prelude` without qualification, with no additional prefix, and without hiding any names. So it defines "bare" names and names prefixed by `Prelude.`, and nothing more.

Here ends the bare basics you need to understand about the module system. Now let's discuss the bare basics you need to understand about typeclasses.

A typeclass includes a class name, a list of type variables bound by that class, and a collection of variables with type signatures that refer to the bound variables. Here's an example:

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: a -> a -> Int
```

The class name is `Foo`, the bound type variable is `a`, and there is only one variable in the collection, namely `foo`, with type signature `a -> a -> Int`. This class declares that some types have a binary operation, named `foo`, which computes an `Int`. Any type may later (even in another module) be declared to be an *instance* of this class: this involves defining the binary operation above, where the bound type variable `a` is substituted with the type you are creating an instance for. As an example, we might implement this for integers by the instance:

```
instance Foo Int where
    foo a b = (a `mod` 76) * (b + 7)
```

Here ends the bare basics you need to understand about typeclasses. We may now answer your question. The only reason the question is tricky is because it falls smack dab on the intersection between two name management techniques: modules and typeclasses. Below I discuss what this means for your specific question.

The module `Prelude` defines a typeclass named `Num`, which includes in its collection of variables a variable named `*`. Therefore, we have several options for the name `*`:

- If the type signature we desire happens to follow the pattern `a -> a -> a`, for some type `a`, then we may implement the `Num` typeclass. We therefore extend the `Num` class with a new instance; the name `Prelude.*` and any aliases for this name are *extended* to work for the new type. For matrices, this would look like, for example,

  ```
  instance Num Matrix where
      m * n = {- implementation goes here -}
  ```
- We may define a different name than `*`.

  ```
  m |*| n = {- implementation goes here -}
  ```
- We may define the name `*`. Whether this name is defined as part of a new type class or not is immaterial. If we do nothing else, there will then be at least two definitions of `*`, namely, the one in the current module and the one implicitly imported from the `Prelude`. We have a variety of ways of dealing with this. The simplest is to explicitly import the `Prelude`, and ask for the name `*` not to be defined:

  ```
  import Prelude hiding ((*))
  ```

  You might alternately choose to leave the implicit import of `Prelude`, and use a qualified `*` everywhere you use it. Other solutions are also possible.

The main point I want you to take away from this is: *the name `*` is in no way special*. It is just a name defined by the `Prelude`, and all of the tools we have available for namespace control are available.

Comment: Thanks! And I assume you want your Prelude stuff to always be available, so that is why you don't want to hide the default (+)?

Comment: Does anybody know how to include preformatted text (code) in a bullet list?

Comment: @drozzy I didn't make any claims about what I want or about what you want. When it's appropriate to hide the Prelude's `+`, then you should hide the Prelude's `+`.

Comment: @Daniel: You just indent the code an extra four spaces (so a total of eight).  I took the liberty of doing that for you (I needed to make sure it worked somehow :-) )

Answer (score 6):

You can implement * as matrix multiplication by defining an instance of Num class for Matrix. But the code won't be type-safe:  * (and other arithmetic operations) on matrices as you define them is not total, because of size mismatch or in case of '/' non-existence of inverse matrices.

As for 'the hierarchy is not defined precisely' - there is also `Monoid` type class, exactly for the cases when only one operation is defined.

There are too many things to be 'added', sometimes in rather exotic ways (think of permutation groups). Haskell designers designed to reserve arithmetical operations for different representations of numbers, and use other names for more exotic cases.

Comment: Sorry I asked for the actual implementation, not the fact that I _can_ do it.

Comment: @drozzy -- no, you said `Can you implement a Matrix class and an * operator that will work on two matrices?`, which nponeccop answered. +1

Comment: No I meant: Can __YOU__ implement it.

Comment: And the answer is "yes I can".

Comment: When somebody says "can I get a witness?" many just respond "amen". A computer scientist, on the other hand, might ask if you're in working in a constructivist logic...