# Qualified import of Data.Map conflicts with Prelude

Tags: haskell, import, module, compiler-errors

I'd like to use `Prelude.map` and `Data.Map.map` for different purposes in my code, but a qualified import of `Data.Map` doesn't seem to help:

```
Prelude> import Data.Map as M
Prelude M> map

<interactive>:3:1:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘map’
    It could refer to either ‘M.map’
                             imported from ‘Data.Map’
                             (and originally defined in ‘containers-0.5.0.0:Data.Map.Base’)
                          or ‘Prelude.map’
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’)
```

(I also took a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZYXg.png) of the error message, [which you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZYXg.png).)

I would like to be able to use `map` and `M.map` respectively; how can I do that?

Comment: You may like the beginning of [my answer to an apparently unrelated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327032/write-this-scala-matrix-multiplication-in-haskell/8331995#8331995).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`import Data.Map as M` imports the names from Data.Map both qualified and unqualified.

To only import qualified names use:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
```