# How do I handle Haskell Prelude namespace collisions?

Tags: haskell

If I want to use `readFile` from `Data.Text.IO`, but there's already a `readFile` in the Prelude, how do I import it, so that it doesn't cause the ambiguity error?

I have a script that just says `import Data.Text.IO` and then later uses `readFile`, and I'm testing it in `ghci` using `:load`, but it complains about ambiguous function calls.

Comment: `import qualified Data.Text.IO as T` and `T.readFile`

Comment: See also [my writing on the Haskell module system and how it interacts with name collision issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331995/791604) on another question. You can stop reading where it says "Here ends the bare basics you need to understand about the module system.". The answers below are imprecise about which bits of their suggestions are *required* to fix the problem and which are just standard practice, which hopefully my other answer will clarify if you care, and will suggest several other solutions (e.g. keep the same import, but use `Data.Text.IO.readFile` instead of `readFile`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two solutions.

```
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
```

This will give you the `Data.Text.IO` function as `T.readFile`. However, if you only plan to use the `Data.Text.IO` version and never the `Prelude` version, you can exclude the `Prelude` version.

```
import Prelude hiding (readFile)
import Data.Text.IO
```

An explicit `import Prelude` will override the default import of `Prelude`, and you can control which names get imported.

Answer (score 2):

`import qualified Data.Text.IO as DTIO`, then you can use `DTIO.readfile`.

see https://wiki.haskell.org/Import for details