# How to use alias in GHCI

Tags: haskell, alias, ghci

Hello i am confronted with the following problem:

I want to test Haskell libraries like `Data.ByteString.Lazy` in the `Ghci`.Do i have to always write the whole name ? 
Are there any aliases available for using in `GHCI`, because i find it very cumbersome to everytime specify if for e.g `readFile` is `putStrLn` is from `Prelude` or  `Data.ByteString.Lazy`

How does one add modules with aliases in GHCI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern ghci supports the full `import` syntax, so you could e.g.

```
> import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS
LBS> LBS.writeFile "foo" (LBS.pack [104,105,10])
LBS> LBS.readFile "foo"
"hi\n"
```

See [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331995/791604) for an in-depth discussion of the things you can do with `import` syntax.

Comment: if you want to get it even shorter you could then enter `rLBS = LBS.readFile` or whatever "alias" you prefer

Comment: Note (not necessarily obvious) if you import multiple modules with the same `as` name their namespaces basically get merged.

Comment: @Cubic Thanks for the suggestion. I've put a link to some further discussion of imports.