# Haskell print Pair

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell.
I got newtype [pair which overloads plus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17768051/3024116)

The code:

```
newtype Pair a b = Pair (a,b)  deriving (Eq,Show)

instance (Num a,Num b) => Num (Pair a b) where
   Pair (a,b) + Pair (c,d) = Pair (a+c,b+d)
   Pair (a,b) * Pair (c,d) = Pair (a*c,b*d)
   Pair (a,b) - Pair (c,d) = Pair (a-c,b-d)
   abs    (Pair (a,b)) = Pair (abs a,    abs b) 
   signum (Pair (a,b)) = Pair (signum a, signum b) 
   fromInteger i = Pair (fromInteger i, fromInteger i)

main = do print Pair (1, 3)
```

When I try to compile the file with `ghc --make` I get the following error message

```
BigNumber.hs:11:11:
    Couldn't match expected type `(t1, t2) -> t0'
                with actual type `IO ()'
    The function `print' is applied to two arguments,
    but its type `((a0, b0) -> Pair a0 b0) -> IO ()' has only one
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: print Pair (1, 3)
    In the expression: do { print Pair (1, 3) }
```

My goal is to create a file that does something to a some sort of `newtype` then prints out the result.

Comment: Note to SO users: this is __not__ a typo problem - it's a precedence issue.

Comment: @AndrewC Full ACK. I think this is one of the most annoying pitfalls for Haskell beginners, because you can't see what you did wrong. Voting to leave open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change you `main` into

```
main = do print (Pair (1, 3))
```

or

```
main = do print $ Pair (1, 3)
```

or (the best option since your `main` consists of a single expression)

```
main = print $ Pair (1, 3)
```

You have to give a single argument to `print`, not 2.