# haskell code compiles on leksah but not ghc

Tags: haskell, ghc, leksah

As the question states, I have some that compiles in leksah but does not compile using `ghc --make filename.hs`

The code:

```
module Main (
    main
) where

pair a b = (Pair (a, b))

newtype Pair a b = Pair (a,b)  deriving (Eq,Show)

instance (Num a,Num b) => Num (Pair a b) where
   Pair (a,b) + Pair (c,d) = Pair (a+c,b+d)
   Pair (a,b) * Pair (c,d) = Pair (a*c,b*d)
   Pair (a,b) - Pair (c,d) = Pair (a-c,b-d)
   abs    (Pair (a,b)) = Pair (abs a,    abs b) 
   signum (Pair (a,b)) = Pair (signum a, signum b) 
   fromInteger i = Pair (fromInteger i, fromInteger i)

main = do   
            a <- return (pair 1 3)   
            print a
            print "haha"  
            print 3.2  
            print [3,4,3]
```

Is there an option I need to invoke to make it run with `ghc --make`?

Disclaimer: I did not make the [pair newtype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17768051/3024116).

Edit:

When using `ghc --make Bignumber.hs` (Bignumber.hs is the filename) the output is

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( BigNumber.hs, BigNumber.o )

BigNumber.hs:20:13: parse error on input `print'
```

Comment: It seems to work for me. What is the specific problem that you're running into?

Comment: @DavidYoung I get the following msg 'BigNumber.hs:21:13: parse error on input `print''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your indentation: maybe you're mixing tabs and spaces in a way that ghc interprets differently than leksah? I don't see another explanation for a parse error at `print`.

Comment: Each line within the `do` should be indented exactly the same (eg, by one tab, or by four spaces).

Comment: Thanks, that was my issue.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear: one tab in Haskell is treated as moving to the next multiple of *eight* spaces, not four.