# In Haskell, if a function returns a "Maybe a" type just so it is safe and total, how is it useful anymore?

Tags: haskell

So I have to define a safe version of the head function that would not throw an error when [] is passed as the argument. Here it is:

```
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead [] = Nothing
safeHead (x:_) = Just x
```

But now, is this function still of any use? Because suppose that type "a" is a Int, then you can add two objects of type Int, but you can't add two objects of type "Maybe Int".

Comment: It forces you to choose what you want to do with `Nothing`.

Comment: Like this: "if Nothing then do something else do another thing instead"?

Comment: But what about the fact that you can no longer add two "Maybe Int"?

Comment: Yes, like that. Maybe you want to propagate it, like `(1+) <$> safeHead l`. Maybe you want to produce a better error message. That kind of thing. You can get an `Int` back out of a `Maybe Int`; there wouldn’t be much point in `Maybe` if you couldn’t.

Comment: You can still add two `Maybe Int`, for instance as `(+) <$> mx <*> my` (you'd get `Nothing` if either `mx` or `my` is `Nothing`, and `Just` the sum if both have values).

Comment: Two relevant blog posts: http://www.parsonsmatt.org/2017/10/11/type_safety_back_and_forth.html http://www.parsonsmatt.org/2018/10/02/small_types.html

Answer (score 8):

"Just" is one such function. Here's how you can use its result (for the ghci REPL):

```
import Data.Foldable (sequenceA_)

let writeLn            = putStrLn . show

let supposedlyUnusable = writeLn <$> Just 0 
sequenceA_ supposedlyUnusable
```

which prints `1` or we can continue to try the other interesting example - using the `Nothing` case

```
let supposedlyUnusable = writeLn <$> Nothing 
sequenceA_ supposedlyUnusable
```

which doesn't print anything.

That's a complete program which works even for other instances of `Traversable` or `Foldable` where you couldn't do a case analysis on the `Maybe` value. `<$>` is the key that lets you apply a function to whatever's contained in the `Maybe` or any `Functor` and if you have two `Maybe`s (or two of the same `Applicative`) you can use the pattern `fn <$> applicative_a <*> applicative_b` which is like `fn a b` but where `a` and `b` are wrapped up things like `Maybe` values.

So that leaves a couple of remaining ways to use a `Maybe` that I can think of, all of which use case analysis:

```
let {fn (Just n) = Just $ 1 + n; fn Nothing  = Nothing}
fn v
-- but that was just a messy way of writing (1+) <$> v
```

...

```
let fn v = case v of {Just n -> Just $ 1 + n; Nothing -> Nothing}
-- and that's the same program with a different syntax
```

...

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
fromMaybe someDefault v
-- and that extracted the `value` from `v` if we had `Just value` or else gave us `someDefault`
```

...

```
let {fn (Just n) = writeLn n; fn Nothing = putStrLn "No answer"}
-- this one extracts an action but also provides an action when there's nothing
-- it can be done using <$> and fromMaybe instead, but beginners tend to
-- find it easier because of the tutorials that resulted from the history
-- of the base library's development
let fn v = fromMaybe (putStrLn "No answer") (writeLn <$> v)
```

oooh, oooh! This one's neato:

```
import Control.Applicative
let v = Just 0 -- or Nothing, if you want
let errorcase = pure $ putStrLn "No answer"
let successcase = writeLn <$> v
sequenceA_ $ successcase <|> errorcase
-- that uses Alternative in which Maybe tries to give an answer preferring the earliest if it can
```

of course we also have the classic:

```
maybe (putStrLn "No answer") writeLn v
```

Comment: `Maybe` doesn’t have a `Comonad` instance (since the methods would need to be partial functions).

Comment: @David Young, very true. I'd gotten my thoughts into a generalised mindset. updated to remove that bit.

Comment: @dfeuer, the `if` example might not be advisable but it's certainly a classic that should be listed for some learners to be comfortable with `Maybe`. BTW `fromMaybe` is already listed and it's better than `maybe` because `maybe a b c` is just `fromMaybe a (b <$> c)` and the `fromMaybe` way uses more general purpose concepts so less knowledge is needed for overall effectiveness if people use that. So listing `maybe` isn't really useful for people.

Comment: @codeshot, I disagree about `maybe` vs. `fromMaybe`. `maybe` is a simple example of a *catamorphism*. These show up all over too: `either`, `bool`, `uncurry`, `foldr`, `foldTree`, etc.

Comment: The `if` example is especially bad to show beginners who may think it's the right way to write Haskell.

Comment: it's okay and they will learn better, but if they don't see it they will only ever be beginners - the current Haskell failure.

Answer (score 8):

As it was mentioned in comments, you can actually add two `Maybe`s. I just wanted to give another point of view on that.

Yes, you can't directly apply `(+)` to `Maybe Int`s, but you can **upgrade** it to another function that is able to do so automatically.

To upgrade **unary** function (like `(+1)`) you write `fmap (+1) maybeInt` or `(+1) <$> maybeInt`. If `(+1)` had type `Int -> Int`, the `fmap (+1)` expression has type `Maybe Int -> Maybe Int`.

Upgrading bin-or-more-ary functions is a bit more complex syntax-wise: `(+) <$> maybeInt <*> maybeInt` or `liftA2 (+) maybeInt maybeInt`. Again, here we promote `(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int` to `liftA2 (+) :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int`.

Handling `Maybe`s this way allows you to build up a computation that works with `Maybe`s out of pure functions and defer checking for `Nothing`. Or even avoid that if you eventually plug it into another function that takes `Maybe` as argument.

Of course, you can use `fmap` and `liftA`s on any `Applicative`, not just `Maybe`.

Answer (score 1):

Safety comes with a cost. The cost is normally extra code, for avoiding error situations. Haskell has given us the way to avoid this at the compile time rather than at run time.

Let me explain with examples from other languages. Though I won't name any language, but it would be apparent which languages I am talking about. Please be sure that all languages are great in their ways, so do not take this as I am finding fault in other language.

In some languages you have pointers and the way you will do `safeHead` is to return either int pointer or null pointer. You will have to de-reference pointer to get the value and when you de-reference null pointer you will get error. To avoid this, extra code will be needed to check for null pointer, and do something when it is null.

In some dynamic languages, you have variables assigned to null. So in above example your variable could be type int or it could be null. And what will happen if you add null to int? Most probably undefined situation. Again special handling needs to be done for the null case.

In Haskell too you will have to do the same, you will have to guard the null situation with extra code. So what's the difference? The difference in Haskell is doing it at the compile time and not at the run time.*  i.e. the moment you have this kind of code along with your definition of safeHead, `p = safeHead xs + safeHead ys`, the code will give error at the compile time. You will have to do something more for addition if type Maybe Int. You can write your function for adding two or multiple Maybe Ints or create newype for Maybe Int and [overload +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308015/can-you-overload-in-haskell) or do something as mentioned in other answers.

But whatever you do, you do it before unit testing. Definitely much before it goes on production. And earlier the error is caught lesser is the cost. That's where the advantage of type safe Haskell comes in handy.

`* There could be mechanism in other languages to handle this at compile time.`