# Overload (*) as a -> b -> c

Tags: haskell, operators

With the following types

```
newtype Kms =
  Kms Double
newtype Hours =
  Hours Double
newtype KmsPerHour =
  KmsPerHour Double
```

I would like to have the following

```
foo :: KmsPerHour -> Hours -> Kms
foo kmsPerHour hours = kmsPerHour * hours
```

Is this possible? In a perfect world the solution would support (/) as well and for several different units (m, m/s, m/s/s for example)

That way I can more easily make sure that all the units I use match up and that the calculations is correct.
The way I do it now (but with several more types of units in different combinations) is

```
foo :: KmsPerHour -> Hours -> Kms
foo (KmsPerHour kmsPerHour) (Hours hours) = Kms $ kmsPerHour * hours
```

I checked this [Can you overload + in haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308015/can-you-overload-in-haskell) and https://hackage.haskell.org/package/alg-0.2.10.0/docs/src/Algebra.html#%2B but those are just a->a->a

## Update

My try looks like this. I really like how it very tightly secures the types and it supports nested types and I do not need to define every type combination but I do not know if this is a good way to go - especially since the type family option seems elegant.

Ofc, the functions below can be changed to operators

```
class Unit a where
  unwrap :: a -> Double
  unitMap :: (Double -> Double) -> a -> a

instance Unit Kms where
  unwrap (Kms x) = x
  unitMap f (Kms x) = Kms $ f x

newtype Per a b =
  Per a
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance (Unit a, Unit b) => Unit (Per a b) where
  unwrap (Per x) = unwrap x
  unitMap f (Per x) = Per $ unitMap f x

multWithUnits :: (Unit a, Unit b) => Per a b -> b -> a
multWithUnits (Per x) z =
  let zVal :: Double
      zVal = unwrap z
   in unitMap (* zVal) x

divWithUnits :: (Unit a, Unit b) => a -> b -> Per a b
divWithUnits x y =
  let yVal = unwrap y
   in Per (unitMap (/ yVal) x)

multUnitWith :: (Unit a, Unit b) => Double -> Per a b -> Per a b
multUnitWith factor = convert (* factor)

divUnitWith :: (Unit a, Unit b) => Double -> Per a b -> Per a b
divUnitWith factor = convert (/ factor)

toKmsPerHour :: Kms -> Hours -> Per Kms Hours
toKmsPerHour kms h = km `divWithUnits` h

distance :: Per Kms Hours -> Hours -> Kms
distance speed time = speed `multWithUnits` time
```

I ommited implementations of Hours, and the instances of Num, Ord and other things to not bloat the post.

```
addKms :: Kms -> Kms -> Kms
addKms k1 k2 = k1 + k2
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Short answer is no, because this would violate the expected closure of a `Num` instance. Longer answer is to checkout the [`units` library](https://github.com/goldfirere/units/blob/master/Data/Metrology/Combinators.hs) which uses the `:/`, `:*`, `:+` etc.

Comment: You might also want to look at the "dimensional" library http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional Warning: advanced type-fu required to understand what is going on here.

Comment: @PaulJohnson, how do `units` and `dimensional` compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a -> b -> c` by itself is clearly a much too weak signature, as it would also allow stuff like

```
  (1`KmPerHour`) * (1`KmPerHour`) :: Hours
```

You do need some restriction on the types. There are broadly two options for that:

- a multi-param type class with fundeps.

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

  infixl 7 ·
  class PhysQttyMul a b c | a b -> c, a c -> b, b c -> a where
    (·) :: a -> b -> c

  newtype Length = Kms {getLengthInKm :: Double} -- deriving Data.VectorSpace.VectorSpace
  newtype Time = Hours {getTimeInHours :: Double}
  newtype Speed = KmPerHour {getSpeedInkmph ::Double}

  instance PhysQttyMul Speed Time Length where
    KmPerHour v · Hours t = Kms $ v*t
  instance PhysQttyMul Time Speed Length where
    Hours v · KmPerHour t = Kms $ v*t
  ```
- a type family that just calculates the type of the product of two operands at compile-time.

  ```
  type family PhysQttyProd a b :: *

  type instance PhysQttyProd Speed Time = Length
  type instance PhysQttyProd Time Speed = Length
  ```

  ...and then you still need a typeclass for the actual value-multiplication

  ```
  class PhysQttyMul a b where
    (·) :: a -> b -> PhysQttyProd a b

  instance PhysQttyMul Speed Time where
    KmPerHour v · Hours t = Kms $ v*t
  instance PhysQttyMul Time Speed where
    Hours v · KmPerHour t = Kms $ v*t
  ```

The latter option looks much complicated, but it has some practical advantages when actually defining your unit system. In particular, it lends itself well to a generic type that can express *any* physical quantity, via essentially the exponents of a set of base units. That's how [the units library](https://github.com/goldfirere/units) does it.

Comment: This looks elegant, I updated my question with my first take on it. I do not have enough knowledge to evaluate the difference between that and a type family solution. Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: @J.Doe I think you ought to revert your edit to the question and post it as a new, follow-up question. otherwise it gets too confusing to follow. Moreover, if your code is working, i.e. you don't have a problem with it and instead ask for a discussion and "thoughts", i.e. a *review*, then the right place to post it might be on CodeReview stackexchange.

Comment: I understand now that my comment and my edit could be misconstrued and made possible the question worse. What I tried to convey was that I potentially have a solution but I cannot see the long term differences between that and the type family one. So maybe I should add it as an answer and people can vote it down if it is not the best solution?

Comment: @J.Doe if you aren't sure in its correctness, it is *not* an answer, so why post it? if you have a question, *ask*. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, giving the `Prelude`'s multiplication operator that type is not possible. But you can make your own operator and give it whatever type you want. You can even name it `(*)` if you want...

```
import Prelude hiding ((*))
import qualified Prelude
KmsPerHour a * Hours b = Kms (a Prelude.* b)
```